# Translating and importing Joy UI dark mode to ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs, joy-ui

I am trying to use Joy UI and its dark mode `https://mui.com/joy-ui/customization/dark-mode/` in my cljs project and am stuck with translating the part below to cljs code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { CssVarsProvider, extendTheme } from '@mui/joy/styles';
import Sheet from '@mui/joy/Sheet';
import Chip from '@mui/joy/Chip';
import Typography from '@mui/joy/Typography';

const theme = extendTheme({ cssVarPrefix: 'demo' });

export default function DarkModeByDefault() {
  return (
    <CssVarsProvider
      defaultMode="dark"
      // the props below are specific to this demo,
      // you might not need them in your app.
      //
      theme={theme}
      // the selector to apply CSS theme variables stylesheet.
      colorSchemeSelector="#demo_dark-mode-by-default"
      //
      // the local storage key to use
      modeStorageKey="demo_dark-mode-by-default"
      //
      // set as root provider
      disableNestedContext
    >
      <div id="demo_dark-mode-by-default">
        <Sheet sx={{ px: 3, py: 1.5, borderRadius: 'sm' }}>
          <Typography
            component="div"
            endDecorator={
              <Chip variant="outlined" color="primary" size="sm">
                Default
              </Chip>
            }
            fontSize="lg"
          >
            Dark mode
          </Typography>
        </Sheet>
      </div>
    </CssVarsProvider>
  );
}
```

I am using `shadow-cljs`, and I tried to translate it like the following

```
(ns ....
  (:require
    ...
   ["@mui/joy/Button" :as mui-joy-button]
   ["@mui/joy/Grid" :as mui-joy-grid]
   ["@mui/joy/styles" :as mui-joy-styles]))

(def btn (rc/adapt-react-class (.-default mui-joy-button)))
(def grd (rc/adapt-react-class (.-default mui-joy-grid)))
(def cvp (rc/adapt-react-class mui-joy-styles/CssVarsProvider))
(def ext mui-joy-styles/extendTheme)

(def theme (ext {:cssVarPrefix "demo"}))

(defn main-page []
  [cvp {:defaultMode "dark"
        :theme theme
        :colorSchemeSelector "#demo_dark-mode-by-default"
        :modeStorageKey "demo_dark-mode-by-default"
        :disableNestedContext true}]
  [:div {:id "demo_dark-mode-by-default"}
   [grd {:container true :spacing 2}
    [grd {:xs 8} [:p "asdasdfasdf"]]
    [grd {:xs 4} [btn {:variant :solid} "asdf"]]]])
```

But the theming and dark mode do not work. I believe my problem is CssVarsProvider part. I am not sure how I can import it.

Can someone please provide a clue?

Comment: Your [:div] is _outside_ of [cvp] (which makes [cvp...] somewhat of a no-op)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(def theme ...)` is calling the `(ext ...)` JS function with a CLJS Map. It won't support that, it will likely need to be either `(def theme (ext #js {:cssVarPrefix "demo"}))` or `(def theme (clj->js {:cssVarPrefix "demo"}))`, so that it is converted to a proper JS Object first. Which one you use depends on if you add nested structures. The `#js` works only for simple objects, which in this case would fit.

You can also shrink the code a bit by using the `:>` operator and the require sugar, so that you don't need all the extra defs.

```clj
(ns ...
  (:require
    ...
    ["@mui/joy/Button$default" :as btn]
    ["@mui/joy/Grid$default" :as grd]
    ["@mui/joy/styles" :as mui-joy-styles :refer (CssVarsProvider extendTheme)]))

(def theme (extendTheme #js {:cssVarPrefix "demo"}))

(defn main-page []
  [:> CssVarsProvider
   {:defaultMode "dark"
    :theme theme
    :colorSchemeSelector "#demo_dark-mode-by-default"
    :modeStorageKey "demo_dark-mode-by-default"
    :disableNestedContext true}
   [:div {:id "demo_dark-mode-by-default"}
    [:> grd {:container true :spacing 2}
     [:> grd {:xs 8}
      [:p "asdasdfasdf"]]
     [:> grd {:xs 4}
      [:> btn {:variant "solid"} "asdf"]]]]])
```

Comment: Your code works like a magic. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

In Clojure only the last expression in a function is returned. In `main-page` you have two components (`cvp` and `:div`), but only the last (`:div`) is returned. You want to nest the `cvp` in the `:div`.

```clj
(defn main-page []
  [cvp {:defaultMode "dark"
        :theme theme
        :colorSchemeSelector "#demo_dark-mode-by-default"
        :modeStorageKey "demo_dark-mode-by-default"
        :disableNestedContext true}
   [:div#demo_dark-mode-by-default
    [grd {:container true :spacing 2}
     [grd {:xs 8} [:p "asdasdfasdf"]]
     [grd {:xs 4} [btn {:variant :solid} "asdf"]]]]])
```

Note that in Hiccup classes can be appended to the first keyword in the vector with `.` and ids with `#`, so I changed `[:div {:id "demo_dark-mode-by-default"`} to the equivalent `:div#demo_dark-mode-by-default`.

Comment: You are right. I updated my code using :<> but there is the real issue lingering.

Comment: Console says module$node_modules$react_dom$cjs$react_dom_development.js:163 Uncaught Error: No protocol method IKVReduce.-kv-reduce defined for type object: [object Object]
    at Object.cljs$core$missing_protocol [as missing_protocol] (cljs.core.js:314:9)
    at cljs$core$IKVReduce$_kv_reduce$dyn_17106 (cljs.core.js:2646:17) ...

Comment: This is incorrect. You want the div to be a child of cvp. Not a separate thing.

Comment: Oh you are right, apologies, I will fix the answer.

Comment: I see @ThomasHeller's answer now, importing the React class using `:>` is even better, I did not check those parts locally.